# How to solve web socket client connection numbers limit

Tags: wcf, websocket

I developed a websocket service and client follow http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/idof/archive/2012/03/06/what-s-new-in-wcf-4-5-websocket-support-part-2-of-2.aspx.
When i test it,i find that only ten clients can connect to the service. Here is my config:

```
<customBinding>
<binding name="customConfig">
<byteStreamMessageEncoding />
     <httpTransport>
     <webSocketSettings transportUsage="Always" createNotificationOnConnection="true" maxPendingConnections="10000" />
          </httpTransport>
        </binding>
      </customBinding>
```

I know for Duplex communication like tcpbinding,set the "maxConnections" property can improve the number of clients who can connect server.But for custombinding,there is no such property.

How can I do to solve it?

I have config the behaive:

```
<serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="serviceBehaive">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
          <serviceThrottling maxConcurrentCalls="100000" maxConcurrentSessions="100000"
            maxConcurrentInstances="100000" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
```

Who can help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I consulted the author with this question.His answer is:
This is a limitation of iis in desktop operating system. On server os there is no limitation, as well as iis express

Thanks for him